# Hololens2 Azure Spatial Anchors Tutorial Crash

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

Trying to follow the [Microsoft Azure Spatial Anchors tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-asa-02) (even after it was recently updated) but the Release build of the project crashes on launch on the device (just after the Unity splash screen). Interestingly a Debug build of the same project seems to launch ok.

I've been able to build, deploy, test both the basic [Hololen2 tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-01) and the [ASA Samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples) as well as some custom projects so don't think this is a general development or deployment issue.

Have others been able to follow this tutorial and successfully deploy to a device recently and/or is there any suggestions to diagnose the issue further?

Setup and Unity packages used (as per the tutorial and linked instructions):

- Hololens OS (up to date): 19041.1136
- Unity 2019.4.19f1
- com.microsoft.azure.spatial-anchors-sdk.core@2.7.1
- com.microsoft.azure.spatial-anchors-sdk.windows@2.7.1
- MRTK Foundation - 2.5.3 from the basic tutorial series (MRTK Package Tool)
- AR Foundation: 3.1.3
- Windows Mixed Reality: 4.2.1 (downgrade from 4.2.3?)
- MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.GettingStarted.2.4.0.unitypackage
- MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.4.0.unitypackage

Note: MRTK.HoloLens2.Unity.Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors.2.4.0.unitypackage listed in the tutorial actually links to a new 2.5.3 package (https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityLearning/releases/tag/azure-spatial-anchors-v2.5.3) however the version file in this package still has 2.4.0??

Exception thrown at 0x00000226E0FBCC40 in Workspace Hololens2 MRTK.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000226E0FBCC40.

Comment: I think through process of elimination this is somehow caused by the DebugWindow prefab's BoundsControl component (as provided in the Tutorials.Assets.AzureSpatialAnchors package from the tutorial). If I disable this one component on the instance of this in the scene then the application loads.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to upgrade the ASA SDK to version **2.7.2** (https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/releases/tag/v2.7.2)?

They have recently fixed an error exactly like the one you're reporting:

- **"The first bug was specific to ARM32 builds running on HoloLens 2 and was manifesting as an access violation crash in SDK during anchor creation or query."**

Comment: Seem to get the same result with that updated package unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problem. Running it without the Debug Window worked for me!